# css and javascript is not working properly for rails 5 project

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to implement a template page in my rails project where it would place all images side by side and when you hover you get the effect of the first image where the square is highlighted with a search symbol and when you click on the search symbol a larger image shows like the second photo. and I cannot figure out why I have all the files I need and have changed the coding to work in rails. It is supposed to look like the image below:

[image: Supposed to look like]
[image: Supposed to look like part 2]

Here is the html code:

```
<!--=== Cube-Portfdlio ===-->
<div class="cube-portfolio">
    <div class="content-xs">
        <div id="filters-container" class="cbp-l-filters-text content-xs">
            <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item"> All </div> |
            <div data-filter=".identity" class="cbp-filter-item"> Identity </div> |
            <div data-filter=".web-design" class="cbp-filter-item"> Web Design </div> |
            <div data-filter=".graphic" class="cbp-filter-item"> Graphic </div> |
            <div data-filter=".logos" class="cbp-filter-item"> Logo </div>
        </div><!--/end Filters Container-->
    </div>

    <div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-agency">
        <div class="cbp-item graphic">
            <div class="cbp-caption">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img src="assets/img/main/img3.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <ul class="link-captions">
                                <li><a href="portfolio_single_item.html"><i class="rounded-x fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="assets/img/main/img3.jpg" class="cbp-lightbox" data-title="Design Object"><i class="rounded-x fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="cbp-l-grid-agency-title">Design Object 01</div>
                            <div class="cbp-l-grid-agency-desc">Web Design</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!--/end Grid Container-->
</div>
<!--=== End Cube-Portfdlio ===-->
```

And here are the files it requires:

```
<!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/css/cubeportfolio.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/custom/custom-cubeportfolio.css">
<!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/smoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
```

Now on my end this is what I am getting:

[image: what I am getting]
[image: what I am getting part 2]

Also here is the html output from my end when I left click and view source it looks very similar to what is above which sort of tells me that something is not right with the css and js files like they are not being loaded into the project :

```
<div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-agency">
                <div class="cbp-item graphic">
                    <div class="cbp-caption">
                        <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                        <img src="/assets/creative/main/img3-972c688b1a840ae0a8ec9b22012ae6c4aa69ca6894da2029277fa2c163b41fc0.jpg" alt="Img3" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                            <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                    <ul class="link-captions">
                                        <li><a class="cbp-lightbox" data_title="Design Object" href="assets/creative/main/img3.jpg">
                                        <i class="rounded-x fa fa-search"></i>
                                        </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-agency-title">Design Object 01</div>
                                    <div class="cbp-l-grid-agency-desc">Web Design</div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the actual code in rails:

```
<div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-agency">
    <div class="cbp-item graphic">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
            <%= image_tag "creative/main/img3.jpg"%>

            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                        <ul class="link-captions">
                            <li><%= link_to "assets/creative/main/img3.jpg", :class => "cbp-lightbox", data_title: "Design Object" do %>
                            <i class="rounded-x fa fa-search"></i><%end%></li>

                        </ul>
                        <div class="cbp-l-grid-agency-title">Design Object 01</div>
                        <div class="cbp-l-grid-agency-desc">Web Design</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my asset pipeline I am using all the files I need (arrows pointing to the files):

Javascript

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require creative/bootstrap.min
//= require creative/animated-headline
//= require creative/back-to-top
//= require creative/smoothScroll
//= require creative/jquery.cubeportfolio.min <------------------------------------------
//= require creative/app
//= require creative/jquery.backstretch.min
//= require creative/backstretch-ini
//= require creative/fancy-box
//= require creative/cube-portfolio-3-ns <------------------------------------------
//= require creative/jquery-migrate
//= require creative/jquery.counterup.min
//= require creative/jquery.fancybox
//= require creative/jquery.parallax
//= require creative/jquery.themepunch.tools.min
//= require creative/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min
//= require creative/modernizr
//= require creative/owl-carousel
//= require creative/owl.carousel
//= require creative/revolution-slider
//= require creative/style-switcher
//= require creative/waypoints.min
//= require creative/wow.min
//= require creative/jquery-ui.min
//= require creative/jquery.validate.min
//= require creative/jquery.maskedinput.min
//= require creative/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min
//= require creative/reg
//= require creative/checkout
//= require creative/datepicker
//= require gmaps/google
//= require creative/infobox
//= require creative/custom
//= require turbolinks
//= require lodash
//= require_self
```

CSS

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require creative/bootstrap.min
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require creative/line-icons
 *= require creative/animated-headline
 *= require creative/animate
 *= require creative/cubeportfolio.min <------------------------------------------
 *= require creative/custom-cubeportfolio <------------------------------------------
 *= require creative/custom
 *= require creative/dark
 *= require creative/default
 *= require creative/footer-v1
 *= require creative/header-v6
 *= require creative/jquery.fancybox
 *= require creative/owl.carousel
 *= require creative/parallax-slider
 *= require creative/settings
 *= require creative/style
 *= require creative/app
 *= require creative/blocks
 *= require creative/page_log_reg_v1
 *= require creative/page_about
 *= require creative/jquery.mCustomScrollbar
 *= require creative/sky-forms
 *= require creative/custom-sky-forms

 *= require_self
*/
```

I cannot figure out why it is not working as the first image any help would be great.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: If you remove turbolinks from the asset pipeline does it work?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Turbolinks did not make a difference